# Where can I obtain official German VFR approach charts?

Tags: visual-flight-rules, germany

I am looking for the official VFR approach charts of German airports. I could found a preview here : airports.de however I do not know where I can find the official ones or where I can order them. This would be useful to purchase the  maps only for the  airports I am interested. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy new year all you passionate aviators ,

Yesss!!! The time is here. All German VFR charts are available **for free** now. Here’s a link to the German VFR AIP. Look under AD for all VFR charts for all airports:

https://aip.dfs.de/basicVFR

Comment: thanks a lot !!! Amazing!

Answer (score 9):

Don't know what this will bring or what to expect, but I found this notification today:

The Aeronautical Information Publication Germany (AIP) can be used free of charge from January 2023. An online version can then be accessed via the AIS-Portal of DFS.

For several years now, DFS has made the current version of the Aeronautical Information Publication (AIP) available free of charge via its aeronautical information services portal at [www.dfs-ais.de](http://www.dfs-ais.de). The German Aeronautical Publication Agency, as publisher of the AIP, will also be making the supplementary volume AIP VFR available in a free version on the AIS-Portal from January 2023.
This will provide all airspace users, whether they are flying IFR or VFR, with easy and free access to the AIP. The two Aeronautical Information Publications (AIP IFR and AIP VFR) will continue to be distributed in the usual form via the online shop of the DFS subsidiary R. Eisenschmidt GmbH.

[Link to the website](https://www.dfs.de/homepage/en/media/press/2022/11-juli-2022-german-aip-vfr-available-free-of-charge/).

Comment: Welcome to the Aviation Stack. This is a great answer to this question. I hope the OP comes back to recognize this contribution!

Comment: Amazing answer ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The official German AIP VFR is only distributed via a company called [Eisenschmidt](http://eisenschmidt.aero/). I'm not even sure, there's a digital version of the official charts. But you can buy [a 2.35kg heavy print version of the VFR AIP](https://www.eisenschmidt.aero/karten-manuals/manuals/vfr/785/aip-vfr-grundwerk). The only thing that comes close to the charts digitally is something called ["VFR eBulletin"](https://secais.dfs.de/pilotservice/user/login/login_edit.jsp), a software, where you can enter your route and see that overlaying an ICAO map - but the map is in very bad resolution and low quality.

Sadly, Germany doesn't do it like [many](https://ais.lgs.lv/eAIPfiles/2018_003_26-APR-2018/data/2018-04-26-AIRAC/html/index.html) [other](http://eaip.samgongustofa.is/) [European](https://aim.naviair.dk/) [countries](https://ais.enaire.es/AIP/AIPS/AMDT_301_2018_AIRAC_04_2018/AIP.html) by publishing their AIP VFR online for free.

Comment: There is a little hope with Foreflight for EU. Apparently they plan on putting the Jeppesen database in their and hopefully also the charts.

Answer (score 0):

http://ww1.jeppesen.com/index.jsp  approach/aviation for charts worldwide.  A paid subscription to a service is usually needed.  That's what the airlines use.  Jeppesen has been in business a long time. Official enough for me. Does Germany have FAA Approach Procedures like the US does? That could be searched for at Germany FAA equivalent websites. Here's the link to US charts to give you an idea of what to look for. faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp

Comment: But do those count as "the official" ones?

Comment: While your points are valid, you should include that information in your answer up front to explain who Jeppesen is and how someone could find official charts there, rather than having to leave comments later.

Comment: I agree Jeppesen covers them, but I would be more interested by the official one. I know that in France there is an official website for all VFR charts